# nth-child and descendant selector not selecting all expected elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, selector

My DOM is as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AHJXk/1/.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text"><input type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"><input type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text"><input type="text">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"><input type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm trying to select all `input`s in the second `td` of each `tr`, i.e. four in total. I thought the following selector would work:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2) input')
```

But it only returns the *first* `input` of each second `td` (two in total). Why is that? If I do:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(1) input')
```

then I do indeed get *all* `input`s of each first `td` (four in total).

So why is `:nth-child(2)` not returning all `input`s but only the first one of each matched `td`?

Comment: Try it on another browser. Congratulations -- you found a webkit bug! It works in Firefox, Opera & IE but not Chrome.

Comment: @jamietre: It is indeed Chrome which I'm working in. In fact, I now discover it *sometimes* works, and *sometimes* doesn't. This is weird... Anyhow, using it in CSS works all the time so guess it's indeed some kind of bug. Thanks!

Comment: Forcing Sizzle to select fixes the bug (as expected), so I'll file a bug report I guess. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/AHJXk/4/

Comment: I noticed that typing "chrome nth-child" into google autocompletes with "bug".. there are a few similar-looking bug reports for chrome & jQuery. Seems to me jQuery ought to fix this, I guess forcing use of sizzle whenever nth-child appears in a query on a webkit browser?? But that's better than not working.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you all four of them:

```
$('input','table tr td:nth-child(2)')
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AHJXk/3/

Comment: Indeed, you're correct. Do you happen to know why though? I don't quite see what difference this makes (except that this one works of course).

Comment: @pimvdb i am not entirely sure myself.