# Striping a table: bug with tr:nth-child td in Chrome/Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to stripe table cells in rows with JavaScript based on their row's position in a table and value, so I thought to use `tr:nth-child(i) td` to grab only the cells (ignoring `th`)...

Here's a fiddle to show the problem (bug?) I've found: http://jsfiddle.net/redroot/pBe94/. As you can probably see i'm striping the `td` elements in the first four rows in the body of the table. In Chrome and Safari, only the first cell is found in the 2nd and 3rd rows, whereas if I find the row first, then use `find("td")` it works fine, as shown in the 4th row.

At first I thought it was my markup, but it seems fine, and it works fine in Firefox. So I'm a little stumped, any help would be appreciated!

(Sme thing happens with `document.querySelectorAll` in my tests, only in Chrome and Safari.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there seems to be some WebKit bug indeed. I also experienced this previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892556/nth-child-and-descendant-selector-not-selecting-all-expected-elements), but the bug has not yet been fixed apparently.

One thing to do is forcing Sizzle to do the selection instead of the native WebKit engine:

```
$.expr[":"].dummy = function() {
    return true;
};
```

Then you can use:

```
$("#rows tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:dummy").css("background-color","#e0e0e0");
```

Since `:dummy` is not available natively, jQuery will use Sizzle (its custom selection library). Going this non-native way is a performance penalty though (as always).

http://jsfiddle.net/pBe94/2/

Comment: Nice quick answer, thanks very much. I'm going to attempt the decouple the jQuery dependency eventually, but this'll be a good start, cheers

Comment: I guess the non-jQuery way would be to find the table row first, then find any child tds ... hmmm

Comment: @redroot: What about using CSS? If I recall correctly, CSS did work fine.

Comment: Yeah that works fine, it needs to be dynamically with JS only with this project however